# Loading validations from a table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to load model validations from a table and validate my model. e.g. I have a database table called validations, which has rows like :

```
validation_action       validation_condition
----------------        --------------------

validates_presence_of    if answer_name is name
validates_format_of      if answer_type is date
```

In my model I want:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

load validation_actions , lambda {if validation_condition is true}
```

Ok more detail:

I am creating an app for taking surveys. I am storing questions in a table and answers in another table. I need to store the validation for each answer in the question table and validate each answer before I accept it. I can query validation for each question and run it in controller but I want to do it in model instead as it is much cleaner.

so two models :

```
Questions -> table questions sas code and details about questions
Answers -> table answers stores answers with a foreign key to Questions.
```

I want to validate the input in Answers model depending upon conditions defined in questions database table.

Please let me know if more detail is needed?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand, at all, why you need to have validations in a database table. Could you flesh out your question with real Model code you're trying to get working and real validation rows from the database?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have Questions which have many associated Answers, and also have associated ValidationActions. When an Answer is being saved, you want to run validations against it based on evaluating code stored in the ValidationActions belonging to it's associated Question object.

This seems like a bad idea. Not so much that validations are conditional on the state of an associated object (the Question), which is the sort of thing that does happen, but that you're doing what amounts to executing code from the contents of the database. This is one of those things that makes web developers twitchy - the security issue is the most obvious reason (that if someone can edit your database's fields, they can cause arbitrary code to run on your system), but it's definitely a questionable practice even outside that (I'm having trouble articulating the reason more convincingly than 'code is code and data is data and never the twain shall meet', but there it is).

All that said, it should be possible to write a custom validator [as explained here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with) to handle this. It will doubtless be inefficient, might well be prone to breakage, and is probably a security hole unless it's written very carefully. But it's possible.